# MPAndroid grouped bar chart values customization

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

M using **MPAndroidChart** library to draw grouped bar chart. I want to achieve customized graph as given in below image. Values of bars will display below its bar with different color same as bars. Is it possible? Any help with code will accepted.

[image]

Comment: You need to create another view below your chart to implement something like this.

Comment: Is it not possible inside the chart? Any reference link for this?

Comment: I dont think so there is a way to do that inside a chart. You need to modify chart library to implement something like this.